# How to call postgresql stored procedure using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have developed stored procedure in postgresql which accepting 2 parameters & I am calling it using sqlalchemy using below code but getting syntax error.

I have tried sqlalchemy online tutorials.

```
connection.execute('stored_proce_name ?, ?',  para_1, para_2 )
```

Getting error like :ProgrammingError('(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "stored_proce_name "\nLINE 1: stored_proce_name ?, ?\n        ^\n')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
result = conn.execute(StoredProc("add", (3, 4), Integer))
```

Comment: what is meaning for Integer here ?

Comment: it is referred to the return type

Comment: Hi @Moon, if my answer was useful for you please consider upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, where does the `StoredProcedure` class come from?

Comment: What in Earth is StoredProc!